# How to find a value by class name in WatiN?

Tags: html, css, watin

I have the below span in an HTML file:

```
<span class="pagenavigation pagecount">page 5 of 9</span>
```

How to find this span using WatiN selectors for classes?

the .Span() method of the ie object accepts only a spanId.

I'd need something like this:

```
ie.SpanByClasses(new[]{"pagenavigation", "pagecount"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a C# solution, you can get the span using

```
Span sp = el.Span(Find.ByClass("pagenavigation pagecount"));
```

where `el` is the parent element such as a Div or even the full Document `ie`.